# is it safe to use a microwave with the outside glass missing?

Tags: electrical, safety, microwave-oven

The *outer* glass on our microwave shattered recently. The part can no longer be purchased. Two related questions:

1. Is it still safe to operate?
2. Can the shattered glass be replaced with plexiglass? It won't look as good, but it'll be an improvement.

[image]

Comment: No (to both questions). The glass (or mesh looking on the glass) prevents the microwaves from getting out of the chamber.

Comment: I've read that as long as the black screen is in place it's supposedly safe to use but I'm not sure I would trust it. If there is any breach in the screen it could cause serious burns.

Comment: Early microwave cookers **did not even have glass**, just the screen which blocks the energy waves. Your screen is in place so my intuition is that it will still work fine, BUT there is a 100% chance that the manufacturer would say "don't use it".

Comment: Actually, a lot of early microwave ovens (my family had a big combination microwave/conventional oven in the 70s - it was fantastic) had a solid metal door instead of glass.

Comment: It's hard to know which specific parts of the door are safety-critical. But if you guess wrong, you (or someone using your microwave) could end up with burns from the microwave radiation. (The outer glass itself is probably not, but what about all that foil visible in the photograph? It looks torn in some places. Assuming it's conductive, it could be part of the safety barrier keeping the microwaves inside the microwave.) Better to just replace the unit.

Comment: i read somewhere that you can check for leaks by using a fluorescent tube

Comment: @jsotola There are actual leak detectors available. I wouldn't trust a fluorescent tube as a *reliable* indicator. Plus I could see someone grabbing an LED tube and then thinking they're safe...

Comment: This falls well into the "cheap in the short term, potentially very expensive in the long term" category. Even with insurance, the hospital bills from any potential injury far out weigh the cost of a new microwave. Heck, the ambulance ride alone will cost you more than a new microwave.

Comment: How many dangerous mistakes have started with:  "I read somewhere..."

Answer (score 16):

#### DANGER, WILL ROBINSON

The glass doesn't stop the microwaves. The mesh does.

However, without that glass in place, the chance of something **else** going wrong - e.g., that foil coming off or some other part coming loose, is drastically increased.

As far as replacing with plastic, I definitely don't recommend it. I'm not against plastic for certain repairs - e.g., quick fix for a broken taillight cover. But for a microwave oven door where the risks are **really high** if something goes wrong, absolutely not.

This falls into the "what you don't know can really hurt you" category. Unlike a conventional oven (just "heat", which you can feel as it melts the plastic you put in there, producing toxic fumes, etc.), with a microwave oven you could undergo serious bodily injury *and not know it is happening until it is too late*.

**No. Just no.**

Comment: Weell... the mesh certainly creates a nodal plane (which becomes a reflective surface for the microwaves - in turn creating a standing wave in the cavity). The glass aids in absorbing whatever radiation **isn't reflected** by that nodal plane. There can certainly be radiation inside the cavity that slips through the mesh. Especially once you put stuff in it, that changes the cavity. I would absolutely not run it with just the mesh. The glass is a janitor, sweeping up what the mesh leaves behind.